# Consume Equals instead of Contains

Tags: vb.net, collections

I got two following class:

Class Part:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class Part
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Part)

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Property _comparisonType As EqualsComparmission

    Public Sub New(ComparisonType As EqualsComparmission)
        Me._comparisonType = ComparisonType
    End Sub

    Public Property PartName() As String
    Public Property PartId() As Integer

    Public Function Equals1(x As Part, y As Part) As Boolean Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of Part).Equals
        If x Is Nothing AndAlso y Is Nothing Then Return True
        If x Is Nothing OrElse y Is Nothing Then Return False

        Select Case _comparisonType
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId
                Return x.PartId = y.PartId
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartName
                Return String.Equals(x.PartName, y.PartName)
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName
                Return x.PartId = y.PartId AndAlso String.Equals(x.PartName, y.PartName)
            Case Else
                Throw New NotSupportedException("Unknown comparison type for parts: " & _comparisonType.ToString())
        End Select
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode1(obj As Part) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of Part).GetHashCode
        Select Case _comparisonType
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId
                Return obj.PartId
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartName
                Return If(obj.PartName Is Nothing, 0, obj.PartName.GetHashCode())
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName
                Dim hash = 17

                hash = hash * 23 + obj.PartId
                hash = hash * 23 + If(obj.PartName Is Nothing, 0, obj.PartName.GetHashCode())
                Return hash
            Case Else
                Throw New NotSupportedException("Unknown comparison type for parts: " & _comparisonType.ToString())
        End Select
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return "ID: " & PartId & "   Name: " & PartName
    End Function

End Class
```

Class PartCollection:

```
Public Class PartsCollection
    Implements ICollection(Of Part)

    Public Property _comparisonType As EqualsComparmission
    Private myList As List(Of Part)

    Public Sub New()
        If myList Is Nothing Then
            myList = New List(Of Part)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ComparisonType As EqualsComparmission)
        If myList Is Nothing Then
            myList = New List(Of Part)
        End If
        Me._comparisonType = ComparisonType
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add(item As Part) Implements ICollection(Of Part).Add
        myList.Add(item)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Clear() Implements ICollection(Of Part).Clear
        myList.Clear()
    End Sub

    Public Sub CopyTo(array() As Part, arrayIndex As Integer) Implements ICollection(Of Part).CopyTo
    End Sub

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of Part) Implements IEnumerable(Of Part).GetEnumerator
        Return New PartsEnumeration(myList)
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer Implements ICollection(Of Part).Count
        Get
            Return myList.Count
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReadOnly As Boolean Implements ICollection(Of Part).IsReadOnly
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function Remove(item As Part) As Boolean Implements ICollection(Of Part).Remove
        Return myList.Remove(item)
    End Function

    Public Function GetEnumerator1() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Return New PartsEnumeration(myList)
    End Function

    Public Function Contains(item As Part) As Boolean Implements ICollection(Of Part).Contains
        Select Case _comparisonType
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId
                Return myList.Exists(Function(x) x.PartId = item.PartId)
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartName
                Return myList.Exists(Function(x) x.PartName = item.PartName)
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName
                Return myList.Exists(Function(x) x.PartId = item.PartId And x.PartName = item.PartName)
            Case Else
                Throw New NotSupportedException("Unknown comparison type for parts: " & _comparisonType.ToString())
        End Select
    End Function
End Class
```

I would like to use Equals1 from Part class instead as code is doing right now and using Contains1 from PartsCollection. I would like to ask you what i have to do in this case? My current code is working but i would like to switch to Equals1 as i created it earlier.

This is test code:

```
Dim myParts As New PartsCollection

    Dim John As New Part With { _
         .PartName = "John", _
         .PartId = 1 _
    }

    Dim Silva As New Part With { _
       .PartName = "Silva", _
       .PartId = 2 _
  }

    Dim Jimmy As New Part With { _
       .PartName = "Jimmy", _
       .PartId = 3 _
  }

    Dim James As New Part With { _
      .PartName = "James", _
      .PartId = 4 _
 }

    myParts.Add(John)
    myParts.Add(Silva)
    myParts.Add(Jimmy)
    myParts.Add(James)

    Console.WriteLine("SEARCHING FOR CONCRETE PART IF EXIST")

    myParts._comparisonType = EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName
    Dim p As Boolean = myParts.Contains(New Part() With { _
      .PartName = "James", _
      .PartId = 45 _
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for having functionality in one place or another is usually based on where it is needed or most useful rather than when it was written.  You can of course, copy the code to whereever you like.

One problem in the current state is that you are have what should be a method argument defined as a Property.  The `comparisonType` will need to be set each time you use it so that you can be sure it is set to what it should be.  Secondly, since it is critical to the compare operation, you should want to see what is being used.

Calling Equals/Contains or whatever else on the collection class does not rule out using the method on the item class.  To use it from a collection class:

```
Public Overloads Function Contains(p As Part, 
          compare As EqualsComparmission) As Boolean

    Dim query = Items.Where(Function(f) p.Equals(f, compare)).ToList
    Return query.Count <> 0

End Function
```

Usage:

```
If myParts.Contains(newP, EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName) Then
```

The functionality for comparing exists in the Part Item class, the collection simply calls it. This also allows you to do:

```
If part1.Equals(part2)
```

The more important thing to note is that the comparison mode to use is passed as an argument, specifying which mode to use for this comparison.  The actual query used would depend on what you need to know.